# javascript Sum all item in array which match same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, properties, sum

I have a JSON like this:

```
  [
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c3e04e5a5423cec34b2e2",
         "code":"khmt",
         "facultyName":"Computer Science"
      },
      "classSize":91,
      "warnedLength":61
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
         "code":"dtvt",
         "facultyName":"Electronics and Telecommunication"
      },
      "classSize":89,
      "warnedLength":44
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
         "code":"dtvt",
         "facultyName":"Electronics and Telecommunication"
      },
      "classSize":59,
      "warnedLength":20
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
         "code":"hkvt",
         "facultyName":"Space Airline"
      },
      "classSize":10,
      "warnedLength":5
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
         "code":"hkvt",
         "facultyName":"Space Airline"
      },
      "classSize":20,
      "warnedLength":10
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
         "code":"hkvt",
         "facultyName":"Space Airline"
      },
      "classSize":30,
      "warnedLength":15
   }
]
```

and i want to have an output like this:

```
[
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c3e04e5a5423cec34b2e2",
         "code":"khmt",
         "facultyName":"Computer Science"
      },
      "totalClassSize":91,
      "totalWarnedLength":61
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
         "code":"dtvt",
         "facultyName":"Electronics and Telecommunication"
      },
      "totalClassSize":148, // total classSize of all class has facultyName is "Electronics and Telecommunication"
      "totalWarnedLength":64 // total warnedLength of all class has facultyName is "Electronics and Telecommunication"
   },
   {
      "faculty":{
         "_id":"5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6de0",
         "code":"hkvt",
         "facultyName":"Space Airline"
      },
      "totalClassSize":60, // total classSize of all class has facultyName is "Space Airline"
      "totalWarnedLength":30 // total warnedLength of all class has facultyName is "Space Airline"
   },
]
```

the output is an array, which sum all `classSize` has same faculty into property `totalClassSize` and sum all `warnedLength` has same faculty into property `totalWarnedLength`

the input is an array and the output still an array as well

i am a beginner in learning code and i am still stuck with this problem for while

thank you so much to help me out, have a good day

Comment: On your input, the `_id` inside `faculty` is unique. So I mean, for the same `_id`, `code` and `facultyName` values are always same?

Comment: you tried something ?

Comment: @Derek.W, seems so, so `_id` is enough and the `code` and `facultyName` should be in a different Object with `_id` as key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can generating new object by grouping the current input array by `faculty._id` as object key, and based on that, you can calculate the `totalWarnedLength` and `totalClassSize` for same object keys.

```js
const input = [{
    "faculty": {
      "_id": "5f9c3e04e5a5423cec34b2e2",
      "code": "khmt",
      "facultyName": "Computer Science"
    },
    "classSize": 91,
    "warnedLength": 61
  },
  {
    "faculty": {
      "_id": "5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
      "code": "dtvt",
      "facultyName": "Electronics and Telecommunication"
    },
    "classSize": 89,
    "warnedLength": 44
  },
  {
    "faculty": {
      "_id": "5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
      "code": "dtvt",
      "facultyName": "Electronics and Telecommunication"
    },
    "classSize": 59,
    "warnedLength": 20
  },
  {
    "faculty": {
      "_id": "5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
      "code": "hkvt",
      "facultyName": "Space Airline"
    },
    "classSize": 10,
    "warnedLength": 5
  },
  {
    "faculty": {
      "_id": "5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
      "code": "hkvt",
      "facultyName": "Space Airline"
    },
    "classSize": 20,
    "warnedLength": 10
  },
  {
    "faculty": {
      "_id": "5f9c53c8a0db8f4240ec6f71",
      "code": "hkvt",
      "facultyName": "Space Airline"
    },
    "classSize": 30,
    "warnedLength": 15
  }
];

const groupBy = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (acc[cur.faculty['_id']]) {
    acc[cur.faculty['_id']].totalClassSize += cur.classSize;
    acc[cur.faculty['_id']].totalWarnedLength += cur.warnedLength;
  } else {
    acc[cur.faculty['_id']] = {
      faculty: cur.faculty,
      totalClassSize: cur.classSize,
      totalWarnedLength: cur.warnedLength
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Nice! (up-voted).
I'd test if `acc[cur.faculty['_id']]==undefined` and set as in your `else` plus `totalClassSize : 0` and `totalWarnedLength : 0`, and then (after `if`) just increase the `total`s.
Simplified: `if(acc[key]==undefined) acc[key]={total:0}; acc[key].total+=cur.total;`.

Comment: thank you so much, it fit perfectly with what i have expected, you saved me, it is my thesis project